# log4j can't locate the database where to put the log messages

Tags: logging, log4j, javadb

I am trying out log4j to do log some information to a persistent datastore. I tried to use java db.

I already created the database, named **firstdb** with the table named **logging_data**.

but when I try to run my mini application, it throws **java.sql.SQLException: Database 'firstdb' not found.**

I don't know why but I can seem to play with the database, query some rows and other stuff using the ij tool.

any suggestions please.?

*my properties file named log4jDB.properties*

```
log4j.logger.LoggerClass=DEBUG,DB

log4j.appender.DB=org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender
log4j.appender.DB.driver=org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver
log4j.appender.DB.URL=jdbc:derby:firstdb
log4j.appender.DB.user=app
log4j.appender.DB.password=

log4j.appender.DB.sql=INSERT INTO LOGGING_DATA VALUES('%x','%d{yyyy-MM-dd}','%C','%p','%m')
log4j.appender.DB.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.DB.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
```

*my test class*

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;

public class LoggerClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LoggerClass.class);
        PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4jDB.properties");
        logger.info("Hello this is a info message");
    }
}
```

also added the embedded driver for java db on my classpath if that would help.

cheers!
*simon*

Answer (score 0):

You must specify database location more precisely. In your log4j file for jdbc connection properteis put path, for example:

```
log4j.appender.DB.URL=jdbc:derby:C:/Temp/firstdb
```

or

```
log4j.appender.DB.URL=jdbc:derby:./firstdb
```

Comment: hey max, thanks for the response but I am not really sure where java db stores its database on the harddrive. but i will try to see if i can find it.

Comment: It is the folder named 'firstdb'. The most probably, it is in the folder where was the context of application creating database. Depends how (with which tool was created)

Comment: alright thanks max again for the help. I will try it out after work. appreciate the help :D

Comment: hey max, I don't know what is the deal wth java db but it works fine on an oracle database. thanks very much